# Deno REPL cannot recognize TypeScript variable declaration

Tags: typescript, deno

I installed Deno 1.0.5 on Windows 10, using Chocolatey. I tried to use Typescript in the Deno REPL, but apparently it cannot recognize TypeScript variable declarations **if the type is set**:

```
 C:\>deno
 Deno 1.0.5
 exit using ctrl+d or close()
 > let x: number;
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
     at evaluate ($deno$/repl.ts:54:34)
     at Object.replLoop ($deno$/repl.ts:156:13)
 > let x: number = 42;
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
     at evaluate ($deno$/repl.ts:54:34)
     at Object.replLoop ($deno$/repl.ts:156:13)
 > let x = 42;
 undefined
 > x
 42
```

Do I need to do something special to make Deno CLI support TypeScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deno REPL does not support typescript yet.

See the following old issue: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/1158 which is still open.

Comment from Ryan Dahl on a [PR](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/3760#issuecomment-590472390) that adds TS support:

*Feb 24, 2020*

> Just a bit more context for future researchers: There are many things
>   we can do to improve the REPL without introducing the TS compiler. We
>   should do those things first (e.g. improve inspect, tab completion).
>   Once we're on par with Node's REPL, we can start looking into how to
>   go beyond that by using typescript.

Comment: Interesting... Then why do they advertise Deno as it "supports TypeScript out of the box"? It should not have been given version 1.0 until such a fundamental feature is not implemented.

Comment: It supports TS out of the box for scripts. Not for REPL.

Comment: I understand that. But the main page (https://deno.land) lists the features of Deno *as a whole*, and it says it "supports TypeScript out of the box". It's a major selling point over Node, so moving to 1.0 without supporting TypeScript in the CLI was an unthoughtful move. It makes people disappointed. I won't give up on Deno because of this, but still...

Comment: I understand your point but don't agree with it. I see the REPL as a secondary thing, Deno is still in its infancy so I don't see a problem with 1.0.0 not having REPL TS support. There's still a lot of more important things to add/improve before adding it in my opinion.

Comment: Sure, but I downloaded it primarily to have an easily accessible TypeScript REPL to test TypeScript code snippets fast :) Thanks for your answer and comments!

Comment: For those who need a TypeScript REPL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

Answer (score 2):

The situation has changed in 2022.

Now deno repl comes with typescript support out of the box:

```
$ deno
Deno 1.23.0
exit using ctrl+d or close()
> let x : number = 3
undefined
> x.
constructor           toFixed               toString              toLocaleString        __defineSetter__      __lookupGetter__      isPrototypeOf
toExponential         toPrecision           valueOf               __defineGetter__      hasOwnProperty        __lookupSetter__      propertyIsEnumerable
```

The only thing you need to do is to upgrade your deno executable to a more recent version.

Not sure exactly when this feature landed. Here is the full changelog for reference: https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/main/Releases.md

Comment: This is probably "Type stripping in the REPL":  https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/10934 -- "It allows TypeScript to be inputted in the REPL and it will transpile it to JS for execution."

Comment: It doesn't really make the REPL type-safe. For example, create a function: `function add(a: number, b: number): number { return a + b; }` I think this function is transpiled immediately to JS because you can call it with string arguments without an error: `add("hello", "world")` returns `"helloworld"`.

Comment: So Deno REPL still doesn't really *support* TypeScript the way ts-node does, which throws an error in the above case: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/

Comment: @kol You are right. They are using `--no-check` in repl by default: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13640